# Federated queries on PARQUET format are not allowed with Legacy SQL

Tags: google-bigquery

When querying an external parquet file from BigQuery, I get the following error:

```
Federated queries on PARQUET format are not allowed with Legacy SQL.
```

I have no need to use Legacy SQL but I don't know how to switch it off.

The steps I've taken to get here are to first create a schema definition file:

```
bq mkdef \
  --source_format=PARQUET \
  --autodetect=true \
  gs://maple-gateboards/2023-05-16_04.38/accel.parquet > /tmp/def
```

And then to run a query using a temporary external table:

```
bq query --external_table_definition=accel::/tmp/def 'select x from accel limit 10'
```

At this point the full error message I see is:

```
BigQuery error in query operation: Error processing job 'maple-data-
warehouse:bqjob_r33714133abeec081_0000018824dfe87e_1': Federated queries on PARQUET format are not allowed with Legacy SQL.
```

How can I "switch off" legacy sql, or otherwise resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there is a `--use_legacy_sql=false` command line option to bq that unfortunately does not show up in the help. I also had to add backticks to my table name:

```
$ bq query --use_legacy_sql=false --external_table_definition=accel::/tmp/def 'select x from `accel` limit 10'

+------+
|  x   |
+------+
| 8614 |
| 8598 |
| 8608 |
| 8644 |
| 8638 |
| 8584 |
| 8598 |
| 8630 |
| 8632 |
| 8596 |
+------+
```

My bq version is 2.0.78

Comment: I prefer to use `--nouse_legacy_sql `